# How to export and use a function using Express?

Tags: javascript, express, express-router

I have two file `alarm.js` and `notifications.js`. In `alarm.js` I need to call a method called `sendPush` from `notifications.js`.

**What I've tried :**
Exporting the function from `notifications.js`:

```
module.exports.sendPush = function(params){
   console.log("sendPush from notifcations.js called");
   console.log(params);
}
```

Importing it in `alarm.js` and use it :

```
let helperNotif = require('./notifications')
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const params = {
        param1: 'a',
        param2: 'b'
    }
    helperNotif.sendPush(params)    
});
```

**The problem:**
I keep getting the error saying `helperNotif.sendPush is not a function`

**The question :**
How can I call this `notification.js sendPush` function from my `alarm.js` file ?

[EDIT] maybe I should add that in `notifications.js` I have some `router.get` and `router.post` and at the end `module.exports = router;`

Comment: You export a named function, so you need to import it by its name `let { sendPush } = require('./notifications')`

Comment: I get `Unhandled rejection TypeError: sendPush is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `notifications.js` ends with `module.exports = router`, that will overwrite your `module.exports.sendPush = ...`. If you want to export both the `router` and the `sendPush`, you can write

```js
function sendPush(params){
   console.log("sendPush from notifcations.js called");
   console.log(params);
}
...
module.exports = {router, sendPush};
```

To import the router elsewhere, you must then write

```js
const {router} = require("./notifications.js");
```

Comment: I get the following error : `throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))`

Comment: How do you import the router?

Comment: `const router = express.Router()`

Comment: That how you _define_ it, how do you _import_ it from `notifications.js` into where you need it?

Comment: It's not my code but as far as I can see each file describing some routes always has `const router = express.Router() ... module.export = router;`

Comment: The `notifications.js` is your code, right? And you say that this contains `module.exports = router`. And you must import these routers somewhere.

Comment: Yes but to create it I took an existing file, I feel like the project isn't using any  import of this router

Comment: Then delete the `module.exports = router`.